# Best way to get payment status

Tags: php, symfony, payum

I'm using Payum bundle with symfony 4 for payment handling (PayPal express) . I want display all payments with their statuses to user. How get payment status by payment model? When i want display status (using HumanStatus class)  from payment model i get "undefinded"  while using metod described in this link https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/symfony/purchase-done-action.md shows proper status (authorized). The problem is that this working metod used token model instead of payment model. Is it possible? How?

Comment: More details are required for other developers to understand and help you with your question. try updating your question with more insights

Comment: Ok now it should be more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found solution. In [PayumServer](https://github.com/Payum/PayumServer) demo application payum authors implement extension which updates  payment model status after each api call ([here](https://github.com/Payum/PayumServer/blob/master/src/Extension/UpdatePaymentStatusExtension.php) is code), extension is enabled in generar payum.yml config file. Drawback of this solution is that when merchant will make operation on payment (e.g. capture) in paypal panel status won't update.